# Post to a Facebook user's wall with cURL PHP

Tags: php, facebook, curl, facebook-graph-api

I'm storing facebook userid's and access tokens. Can i post to a selected user's wall with this information? The following code is found here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/
I'm just not sure how to run it with php.

```
curl -F 'access_token=$accessToken' \
     -F 'message=Check out this funny article' \
     -F 'link=http://www.example.com/article.html' \
     https://graph.facebook.com/$facebookid/feed
```

Comment: What about using PHP's [cURL API](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)?

Comment: I doubt that this will work but I will try it :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
$attachment =  array(
'access_token' => $token,
'message' => $msg,
'name' => $title,
'link' => $uri,
'description' => $desc,
'picture'=>$pic,
'actions' => json_encode(array('name' => $action_name,'link' => $action_link))
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://graph.facebook.com/fbnameorid/feed');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  //to suppress the curl output 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: when ever I run this code from the browser it works. But when I run this in console i get {"error":{"message":"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}

Comment: Thanks and to add what I figured out: to upload a picture from your server, change the request url to: https://graph.facebook.com/fbnameorid/photos and add an array item called 'file' with value '@'. [path to file]

Answer (score 3):

Use [Facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/). It's much better than handling CURL by yourself.

Comment: Perhaps you could note what specific functions in the Facebook SDK could replace this code instead of pointing to the entire SDK.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the cURL method but I don't know what should be $action_name and $action_link changed to.

```
<?php
require_once("facebooksdk/facebook.php");
require_once('config.php');

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => $appId,
'secret' => $appSecret,
'cookie' => true
));

$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
echo $access_token;
$msg = "testmsg";
$title = "testt";
$uri = "http://somesite.com";
$desc = "testd";
$pic = "http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/d18eea9d28f3490b8dcbfa9e38f8336e.jpg";
$attachment =  array(
'access_token' => $access_token,
'message' => $msg,
'name' => $title,
'link' => $uri,
'description' => $desc,
'picture'=>$pic,
'actions' => json_encode(array('name' => $action_name,'link' => $action_link))
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  //to suppress the curl output
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);


?>
```

I get the access token successfully, so only these 2 parameters are what I need.

Comment: Just add something like:`
 $action_name = 'Register Now';
 $action_link = 'https://example.com/register/';`