# Can't post to Facebook wall through cURL

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post a message through cURL but I keep getting an error:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#1500) The url you supplied is invalid","type":"OAuthException","code":1500}}
```

Here is my code:

```
$this->msgData['message'] .= 'Test Message';
$this->msgData['link'] = 'test Link';
$this->msgData['name'] = 'Ny test Name';
$this->msgData['access_token'] = 'myaccesstoken';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$this->page_id.'/feed');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);

// execute and close
$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I know that the offline access token has been deprecated but you can still use it by disabling "Remove offline_access permission" in app setting.

I have researched online but I couldn't find much info why this is failing. What URL it means when it says that the URL supplied is invalid? Is the "link" of the CURL URL?

Any suggestions guys?

Comment: I take it that when you echo/log 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$this->page_id.'/feed', you the URL is valid and correct?

Comment: Yes. I echoed the URL. Then I pasted in the browser. It then threw an error saying access token required. So, I added ?access_token=myaccesstoken and it pulled the feed from that page. So, I think that the URL is valid.

Comment: Perhaps try removing the `access_token` from `msgData` and appending it to the URL, as you tried?

Comment: @CallumMcLean: I tried doing that. But it didn't worked :(. Surprisingly, I have another app that uses the same code with some "content" difference and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add this as a comment because I don't have a high enough reputation, so apologies for posting it as an answer; however, is the version of PHP you're running set-up to handle SSL?  Since Open Graph requires https, you may need to tell cURL how to handle it.  Check out the accepted answer to this question:
[Post to a Facebook user's wall with cURL PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814158/post-to-a-facebook-users-wall-with-curl-php)

The lines that you may want to try adding in particular are:

```
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);`
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested. Didn't work :(. Still same error.