# Facebook POST HTTP curl in PHP

Tags: php, facebook, curl, http-post

Teaching myself some Facebook feed posting via PHP and I'm trying to figure out how I would execute this curl HTTP POST via the the PHP curl command, any suggestions?

```
curl -X POST \
     -F 'message=Post%20with%20app%20access%20token' \
     -F 'access_token=YOUR_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN' \
     https://graph.facebook.com/4804827/feed
```

It's found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/publishing-with-app-token/)

Comment: Or is this still a valid article? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814158/post-to-a-facebook-users-wall-with-curl-php

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Comment: You found a nice "article", then why do you ask whether it's still valid before having tried?

Comment: Didn't understand it fully, didn't see it until after making this post, and considering what I've been reading about Facebook Development it most likely had aged out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to do it:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/4804827/feed");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'message' => 'Post with app access token',
    'access_token' => 'YOUR_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN'
));

echo curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I recommend looking at the documentation:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: For some reason I wasn't putting two and two together for the documentation, this makes perfect sense now, thanks.