# PHP cURL to login to facebook

Tags: php, facebook, cookies, curl, authentication

I am attempting to login to Facebook using curl, but everything I have tried has ended up in Facebook saying, "Cookies are not enabled on your browser. Please enable cookies in your browser preferences to continue."

```
$login_email = 'email';
$login_pass = 'password';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.facebook.com/login.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'email='.urlencode($login_email).'&pass='.urlencode($login_pass).'&login=Login');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.facebook.com");
$page = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error($ch));
echo $page;
```

The cookie file 'cookies.txt' exists, and has 644 permissions.
I have also attempted to use multiple of the snippets online, but they all give the same error. I cannot continue with my current project until I get this working and I am able to navigate Facebook using curl as well. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This may help:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
```

Check this answer:

[Post to a Facebook user's wall with cURL PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814158/post-to-a-facebook-users-wall-with-curl-php?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by adding the following:

curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, false);

Answer (score 1):

This must be used on curl cookie :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, getcwd () . '/mirazmac_cookie.txt' );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, getcwd () . '/mirazmac_cookie.txt' );
```

Answer (score -5):

Better to use  use [facebook login sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/)

Because Facebook constantly makes changes to their source code.

Comment: Not exactly what I was going for. Because, what I am attempting to do is not in Facebook's SDK...