# How to login to girisv3.itu.edu.tr with php/curl?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to login this website över mu website (i.e localhost)
https://girisv3.itu.edu.tr/Login.aspx

According to example code shared at here for facebook login on other website (localhost)
[PHP cURL to login to facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23186168/php-curl-to-login-to-facebook)

I am trying to apply this Facebook login for itu.edu.tr login. But it didnt work. I am also newbie to curl and php. How can I do that for this website (itu.edu.tr)?

```
<?php
    $username = 'username@itu.edu.tr';
    $password = 'password';
    $loginUrl = 'https://girisv3.itu.edu.tr/Login.aspx';

    $ch = curl_init();


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'ContentPlaceHolder1_tbUserName='.$username.'&ContentPlaceHolder1_tbPassword='.$password.'&ContentPlaceHolder1_btnLogin=Login');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.itu.edu.tr");
    //execute the request
    $content = curl_exec($ch);

    echo $content;
?>
```

Comment: Did you check the answer to the question with the sample code you linked to?

Comment: @danwebb They are not same. This advised facebook code only works for facebook. When I changed it for the website that I want to login, it doesnt work. Can anyone present a solution for that website?

Comment: @danwebb this guy is very confused, i have written [code that logs into facebook](https://github.com/divinity76/msgme/blob/master/src/php/relays/facebook.relay.php), and the login system at `girisv3.itu.edu.tr` has nothing in common with the login system facebook uses (they both use cookies and they both use the HTTP protocol, but that's all), and no, it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @hanshenrik I see now that I misunderstood the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the login system at `girisv3.itu.edu.tr` has little in common with the facebook login system (i can say that with confidence because i've studied facebook's login system and written [code that logs into facebook](https://github.com/divinity76/msgme/blob/master/src/php/relays/facebook.relay.php) )

to login here, first hit `https://girisv3.itu.edu.tr/Login.aspx` with a simple HTTP GET request, here you'll be redirected **5 times** (why? no friggin idea, albeit at least 2 of them are to test that you have cookies enabled) with [`HTTP Location`-redirects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) , on the first redirect you will get a cookie looking like `Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=fzwd05uqv2ogyvj2p4ip2x3u; path=/; HttpOnly`, save that and re-use it on all following redirects (if you do not, you will get an error like `The ITU Introduction application uses cookies. Your browser has been found to block cookies. Please allow cookies from the browser settings and try again later.`), and on the last request you will get a cookie looking like `Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=nmhigw3julmzbedva0zwklj2; cookieCheck=true`, this is the cookie you need to actually log in. (`cookieCheck=true` probably means that you passed the cookie test), once you're finished with the redirects, the HTML contains a lot of data that you need to parse out to log in, a `<form` element contains a unique url specific to your cookie where you need to send the POST request to log in, it looks like

```
<form method="post" action="./Login.aspx?subSessionId=543cf6e7-d262-46f3-8207-740d92298bd3&amp;currentURL=https%3a%2f%2fportal.itu.edu.tr%2flogin.aspx%3fReturnUrl%3d%252fapps%252fdefault%252f&amp;cookieAdded=true" id="form1">
```

and there are a bunch of `<input>` elements containing data that you also need to parse out and add to the actual login request, specifically

`__VIEWSTATE` and `__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR` and `__EVENTVALIDATION` and `ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hfAppName` and `ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hfToken` and `ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hfVerifier` and `ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hfCode` and `ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hfState` and (this 1 is the login username by the way) `ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tbUserName` 
and (this 1 is the login password) `ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tbPassword` and `ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnLogin`

once you have the login POST data parsed out from the html, add the login username to `ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tbUserName` and add the login password to `ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tbPassword`, and send the actual login request to the url obtained from the `<form` element together with the cookie received in the last http-redirect, the data must be encoded in the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`-format (and PHP has a native function for encoding php arrays in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`-format called `http_build_query`)

here is an example with [hhb_curl](https://github.com/divinity76/hhb_.inc.php/blob/master/hhb_.inc.php) (a php curl_ api wrapper which takes care of error detection (turning silent curl errors into RuntimeExceptions), cookies, following Location redirects, freeing curl resources, and then some)

```
<?php
declare (strict_types = 1);
const USERNAME = "TheUsername";
const PASSWORD = "ThePassword";
require_once('hhb_.inc.php');
$hc = new hhb_curl('', true);
$html = $hc->exec('https://girisv3.itu.edu.tr/Login.aspx')->getStdOut();
$domd = @DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXPath($domd);
$loginForm = $domd->getElementById("form1");
$login_url = 'https://girisv3.itu.edu.tr/' . $loginForm->getAttribute("action");
$postDataInputNames = array(
    '__VIEWSTATE',
    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR',
    '__EVENTVALIDATION',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hfAppName',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hfToken',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hfVerifier',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hfCode',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hfState',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tbUserName',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tbPassword',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnLogin',
);
$postData = [];
foreach ($postDataInputNames as $name) {
    $ele = $xp->query('.//input[@name=' . xpath_quote($name) . ']', $loginForm);
    if (!$ele->length) {
        var_dump($html);
        throw new \LogicException("failed to find input form {$name}!");
    }
    $ele = $ele->item(0);
    $postData[$name] = $ele->getAttribute("value");
}
$postData['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tbUserName'] = USERNAME;
$postData['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tbPassword'] = PASSWORD;
var_dump('login post data: ', $postData);
$html = $hc->setopt_array(array(
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($postData),
    CURLOPT_URL => $login_url,
))->exec()->getStdOut();
$domd = @DOMDocument::loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $html);
$xp = new DOMXPath($domd);
$loginError = $domd->getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_lbHata");
if ($loginError && !empty(trim($loginError->textContent))) {
    echo "LOGIN ERROR: " . trim($loginError->textContent) . "\n";
} else {
    echo "Login success! ";
    var_dump($html);
}


//based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/1352556/1067003
function xpath_quote(string $value) : string
{
    if (false === strpos($value, '"')) {
        return '"' . $value . '"';
    }
    if (false === strpos($value, '\'')) {
        return '\'' . $value . '\'';
    }
    // if the value contains both single and double quotes, construct an
    // expression that concatenates all non-double-quote substrings with
    // the quotes, e.g.:
    //
    //    concat("'foo'", '"', "bar")
    $sb = 'concat(';
    $substrings = explode('"', $value);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($substrings); ++$i) {
        $needComma = ($i > 0);
        if ($substrings[$i] !== '') {
            if ($i > 0) {
                $sb .= ', ';
            }
            $sb .= '"' . $substrings[$i] . '"';
            $needComma = true;
        }
        if ($i < (count($substrings) - 1)) {
            if ($needComma) {
                $sb .= ', ';
            }
            $sb .= "'\"'";
        }
    }
    $sb .= ')';
    return $sb;
}
```

which yields:

```
LOGIN ERROR: Kullanıcı adı veya şifre hatalı.
```

which means the username/password is invalid, because apparently `TheUsername` and `ThePassword` is not valid login credentials.

all the information required to login can be obtained by installing Fiddler Proxy, and record logging in with a browser (like FireFox), and then replicate the browser login procedure with php/curl, which is basically what i did here.